# R : Large (?) visNetwork rendered poorly

Tags: r, vis.js

I'm trying to represent a care network(`disease -> hospital`) . I use visNetwork for that. Here's some details on my network : 2540 vertices and 15776 edges. Here the results when using only 1000 edges : 
[image: visNetwork with 1000 edges]
whereas with only 500 edges it's readable: [image: visNetwork with 500 edges]
There after the code which permits these graphs :

```
visNetwork(nodes=vn_nodes,edges = vn_edges, height = "1000px",width="100%")%>%
visPhysics(enabled = FALSE)%>%
visLayout(randomSeed = 12)
```

I played a little bit with options but without results. Any Ideas to make it usefull or do I need to change package (I've tried networkD3 without real satisfaction either)?

Edit : (add some data)

For [edges](https://framabin.org/?62a01b70ce951ca2#XgJrf2bmWaIOJDum9sPGDmSrg4/N2J1CqZZoS7Cb5hI=)

```
    >vn_nodes
           label   id title group
3     INSEE06004 2469   123     I
4     INSEE06088 2470  2393     I
5     INSEE10387 2471    91     I
6     INSEE13055 2472    75     I
7     INSEE13056 2473    54     I
8     INSEE13205 2474  4192     I
9     INSEE14118 2475   443     I
11    INSEE20004 2477    13     I
12    INSEE20033 2478    32     I
13    INSEE21231 2479  2309     I
14    INSEE25056 2480    35     I
15    INSEE28085 2481    48     I
16    INSEE29019 2482  2266     I
18    INSEE30189 2484   194     I
19    INSEE33063 2485  3080     I
20    INSEE34172 2486  5245     I
21    INSEE35238 2487  3869     I
22    INSEE37261 2488  2639     I
23    INSEE38516 2489  2493     I
25    INSEE44109 2491  3083     I
26    INSEE49007 2492  1330     I
27    INSEE51454 2493  1144     I
28    INSEE54395 2494  1304     I
30    INSEE54547 2496  1839     I
31    INSEE56260 2497   412     I
33    INSEE59183 2499   220     I
34    INSEE59350 2500  7339     I
35    INSEE59606 2501   351     I
36    INSEE60340 2502    32     I
37    INSEE62041 2503   706     I
38    INSEE62160 2504    10     I
39    INSEE62498 2505  1019     I
40    INSEE63113 2506  1526     I
41    INSEE64102 2507    50     I
42    INSEE64445 2508    15     I
43    INSEE67482 2509  3382     I
44    INSEE69029 2510  2905     I
45    INSEE71076 2511    71     I
46    INSEE72181 2512  1312     I
47    INSEE75112 2513   460     I
48    INSEE75113 2514   342     I
50    INSEE75115 2516  3333     I
51    INSEE75118 2517    15     I
52    INSEE75119 2518  6813     I
53    INSEE78498 2519    84     I
54    INSEE80021 2520  2378     I
55    INSEE83050 2521   116     I
56    INSEE83137 2522   285     I
57    INSEE84007 2523   132     I
58    INSEE86194 2524  1351     I
59    INSEE89024 2525    68     I
61    INSEE92024 2527     5     I
62    INSEE92025 2528   101     I
63    INSEE93010 2529    87     I
64    INSEE94028 2530   560     I
65    INSEE95500 2531   126     I
66    INSEE97120 2532   464     I
67    INSEE97209 2533   229     I
69    INSEE97302 2535   389     I
70    INSEE97311 2536   233     I
71    INSEE97416 2537   895     I
72    INSEE98735 2538   121     I
73    INSEE98818 2539    44     I
74       ORPHA10   35     3     O
89      ORPHA100  374     3     O
108  ORPHA100011 1510     1     O
110  ORPHA100013 2179     1     O
111  ORPHA100031 1038     1     O
120  ORPHA100033 2461     1     O
121  ORPHA100043 1946     1     O
122  ORPHA100092 1170     1     O
124    ORPHA1001  136     4     O
140  ORPHA100973   27     7     O
158  ORPHA100980  761     5     O
171  ORPHA100981 1649     3     O
175  ORPHA100982 1342     4     O
181     ORPHA101 2142     2     O
182  ORPHA101016  762     1     O
192  ORPHA101023  289     1     O
218  ORPHA101029 1912     1     O
219  ORPHA101033 1708     1     O
220  ORPHA101038 1010     1     O
226  ORPHA101039  763     4     O
232  ORPHA101063  764     1     O
238  ORPHA101070 1511     2     O
244  ORPHA101075 1512     1     O
247  ORPHA101076 1513     1     O
250  ORPHA101081  834     3     O
265  ORPHA101082 1786     1     O
267  ORPHA101088 1913     3     O
268  ORPHA101090 1861     1     O
270  ORPHA101097 1343     1     O
272  ORPHA101150 1344     1     O
275  ORPHA101330  765     1     O
278  ORPHA101685  290     4     O
329    ORPHA1018 1810     2     O
330  ORPHA101944 1011     1     O
334  ORPHA101950  766     1     O
335    ORPHA1020 1391     1     O
336  ORPHA102002  291     3     O
355  ORPHA102009 1012     1     O
358  ORPHA102010  767     1     O
366  ORPHA102013  292     2     O
368  ORPHA102283   28    31     O
418  ORPHA102284   29     4     O
469  ORPHA102285  293     1     O
517  ORPHA102369   30    12     O
555  ORPHA102373 1345     1     O
556    ORPHA1027 2019     1     O
557     ORPHA103  375     1     O
573    ORPHA1031 1241     1     O
578    ORPHA1034  137     1     O
609    ORPHA1037  138     3     O
627  ORPHA103918 1787     1     O
628     ORPHA104 1043     3     O
647  ORPHA104003 2127     1     O
648  ORPHA104007 1171     1     O
651  ORPHA104009 2128     1     O
653  ORPHA104010 1788     1     O
656  ORPHA104013 1789     1     O
657  ORPHA104075 2288     1     O
658    ORPHA1041  890     3     O
674    ORPHA1046 1811     1     O
675    ORPHA1047 1555     1     O
676    ORPHA1048  891     4     O
697     ORPHA105 1356     1     O
704    ORPHA1052  325     1     O
723    ORPHA1053 1556     1     O
726    ORPHA1054  494     1     O
731    ORPHA1055 1392     1     O
732    ORPHA1057 1242     1     O
735    ORPHA1059 1670     1     O
738     ORPHA106    7     7     O
789    ORPHA1062 1671     1     O
790    ORPHA1064 2218     1     O
791    ORPHA1065 1557     1     O
796    ORPHA1068 2260     1     O
797     ORPHA107   48    12     O
830    ORPHA1071  345    10     O
844    ORPHA1072 1393     1     O
846    ORPHA1081  495     1     O
848    ORPHA1083  496     1     O
853    ORPHA1084 1558     3     O
856    ORPHA1088 2429     1     O
857  ORPHA108959 1709     1     O
859  ORPHA108961 1990     1     O
860  ORPHA108963 1013     1     O
861  ORPHA108967 1014     1     O
865  ORPHA108969 1947     2     O
868  ORPHA108971 1514     1     O
872  ORPHA108973 2129     1     O
873  ORPHA108977  294     1     O
877  ORPHA108979 1991     1     O
878  ORPHA108981  768     1     O
890  ORPHA108983 1650     1     O
892  ORPHA108985  355     1     O
898  ORPHA108989 1515     1     O
910  ORPHA108991 1172     2     O
913     ORPHA109  376     1     O
923  ORPHA109007  295     3     O
940  ORPHA109009  769     1     O
946  ORPHA109011  296     1     O
969      ORPHA11  836     1     O
972     ORPHA110   49     1     O
1003   ORPHA1104 1243     1     O
1004    ORPHA111 1044     2     O
1010   ORPHA1114  497     1     O
1017   ORPHA1117 2313     2     O
1018   ORPHA1118 1953     1     O
1021    ORPHA112   50     2     O
1033   ORPHA1125 1077     1     O
1039   ORPHA1126 1672     1     O
1040    ORPHA113 1207     1     O
1042   ORPHA1132  498     2     O
1045   ORPHA1134 1078     1     O
1046   ORPHA1135 2219     1     O
1047   ORPHA1136 1394     1     O
1061   ORPHA1138 1673     1     O
1062   ORPHA1143 1079     1     O
```

Comment: Can you share the data set (maybe anonymized)? Do you need an interactive graph? You could play with alpha transparency and repulsion. However, I don't think this will work well with so many edges. Instead, you might want to use gephi and an svg export maybe?

Comment: I need interactive graph. I can't use repulsion because I've disabled `visPhysics()`. In the past I used gephi but I'm not an expert on network algorithm and it's easier for me to play only in R. It's difficult for me to share all the data but I've provided a sample.

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: I'm afraid the sample isn't enough to let one play around with the data a bit and try things out. Voting to close as it remains unclear what the result should be.

Comment: @CJYetman : I would like it's look like the one with anly 500 edges. My problem is that there all stack in a small circle meanwhile there's room for a more exploded rendering

Comment: @LukeA : there are research/patient data. It's not simulated data. I will try to make a dummy dataset for you to play with

Comment: with networkD3 you can adjust the 'linkDistance' and the 'charge' (repulsion is negative values) so that the plot spreads beyond the viewing window... and then you can move the viewing window around and/or zoom in an out

Comment: @CJYetman I've tried also networkD3 but I really like the selector that visNetwork offer and the results seems clearer with visNetwork than networkD3

Comment: @LukeA : I've published some extended data (nodes and a link to edges)

Comment: @AmanGast I doubt that your problem is a matter of package; it seems that you don't know the message, which you want to convey to your readers, yet. I put an answer below that shows how to try out different layouts in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't use repulsion because I've disabled

FWIW, here's how you can try out all the [different layout algorithms](http://igraph.org/r/doc/layout_.html) and their parameterizations:

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)
library(qgraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(vn_edges)
V(g)$color <- bipartite.mapping(g)$type + 1L
V(g)$title <- V(g)$name
set.seed(1)
coords <- qgraph.layout.fruchtermanreingold(
  as_edgelist(g, names = F), 
  weights=E(g)$value,
  vcount=vcount(g), 
  area=vcount(g)^2, 
  repulse.rad=vcount(g)^3
)
visIgraph(g) %>% 
  visEdges(width = "value", title="value", color = list(highlight="#ff0000", opacity = .8)) %>% 
  visIgraphLayout("layout.norm", layoutMatrix = coords)
```

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that I can bypass visPhysics with igraph and qgraph. Thanks

Comment: @AmanGast you don't necessarily need qgraph, you can also try out the igraph layout algorithms. Just follow the link... If you found a solution, feel free to add/share it, as others (including me) will probably find it usefull, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the collision and other option so that label do not overwrite scaling.label.enabled

Check the all option from nice documentation of network. [enter link description here](http://visjs.org/docs/network/)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but this option doesn't improve the results.

Comment: plz visit the link i have given above.. i have created then network digram having more then 1500 nodes and it do not overwrite either your edge relation is very close dependent you can check the option and make the proper width and physics to get the clear view.